# How to solve SSL problems behind corporate proxy?

Tags: proxy, ssl

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on my company laptop. All is fine when I work from home. However, when I'm in office and working behind a company proxy I start facing SSL issues.

I've been provided with a cert file that I've imported into my Chrome and Firefox browsers. With that my browsers are able to function correctly. However, curl/wget and basically every other tool connecting to HTTPS is running into issues.

Sample wget failure

```
root@HOST:~# wget -v --no-check-certificate  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store
--2023-04-07 11:57:11--  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store
Resolving ubuntu.com (ubuntu.com)... 185.125.190.20, 185.125.190.21, 185.125.190.29, ...
Connecting to ubuntu.com (ubuntu.com)|185.125.190.20|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I've already added the certs from the CLI by running these commands but to no avail.

```
cp myorg.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
update-ca-certificates
```

What else am I missing? Appreciate the help.

---

Some more debugging info

```
root@HOST:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# openssl s_client -connect ubuntu.com:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
CONNECTED(00000003)
80BB91E2547F0000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:../ssl/statem/extensions.c:879:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 85 bytes and written 319 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 6BC5F74F9BD4FD98F598BFE7D0DFF4DF8D90CB2057DF2E3D6F3AB3138E5EE9D2
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1681111673
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

Comment: Maybe you need to specify a proxy to use?

Comment: if the anwser does not work PM me with a comment please; i''l remove or improve it. Below worked for me a couple of weeks ago ;)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'll check on the proxy part. However, the same cert has been imported in Chrome/Firefox without specifying a proxy and there things are working fine.

Answer (score 2):

The 'unsafe legacy renegotiation' is a SSL flag that has been disabled by default in Openssl v3+. Previous versions (since ~2010) had this flag enabled.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_get_secure_renegotiation_support.html

> #### SECURE RENEGOTIATION
>
> OpenSSL always attempts to use secure renegotiation as described in RFC5746. This counters the prefix attack described in CVE-2009-3555 and elsewhere.
>
> [...]
>
> ##### Patched OpenSSL client and unpatched server
>
> If the option **SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT** or **SSL_OP_ALLOW_UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION** is set then initial connections and renegotiation between patched OpenSSL clients and unpatched servers succeeds. If neither option is set then initial connections to unpatched servers will fail.
>
> Setting the option SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT has security implications; clients that are willing to connect to servers that do not implement RFC 5746 secure renegotiation are subject to attacks such as CVE-2009-3555.
>
> OpenSSL client applications wishing to ensure they can connect to unpatched servers should always set SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT

To resolve the error, we need to modify `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` file

> **IMPORTANT** changes to this file will apply system-wide.

Go to the end of the file, and you should see the following lines:

```
[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2
```

Due to a [defect in OpenSSL v3.0.2](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18295), the `UnsafeLegacyServerConnect` flag has no affect. Check your SSL version by running `openssl version -a` command, the first line contains the version. I have

```
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
built on: Wed May 24 17:12:55 2023 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
```

Add the following line based on your version, immediately after the `CipherString =` line (no empty line in between):

###### For SSL v3.0.2 and older

```
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

###### For SSL v3.0.4+

```
Options = UnsafeLegacyServerConnect
```

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_CONF_cmd.html

> **UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation**: permits the use of unsafe legacy renegotiation. Equivalent to SSL_OP_ALLOW_UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION.
>
> **UnsafeLegacyServerConnect**: permits the use of unsafe legacy renegotiation for OpenSSL clients only. Equivalent to SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT.

Test the changes using `s_client`:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect ubuntu.com:443
```

The output should now contain the server certificate chain, indicating the connection was successful.

#### Alternative: disallow use TLSv1.2

I only see this error when TLSv1.2 protocol is used. An alternative solution, is to set the minimum allowed protocol version. To achieve this, instead of adding the `Options =`  line above, add:

```
MinProtocol = TLSv1.3
```

Test the changes using the `s_client` above.

In the output, you can identify the protocol version, similar to the following (ciphers may be different based on the server you are connecting to):

###### TLSv1.2

```
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

###### TLSv1.3

```
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Answer (score 0):

I have in my instruction: Copy the .pem file to (so not the crt file unless that is in pem format of course) (`cat server.crt server.key >server.pem`

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
```

and do

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

and that should have it add the certificate to the wget command when needed.

---

You can also use wget with the certificate (at least) itself in 2 ways if needed:

```
wget --ca-certificate={file.pem}
```

or add it to `~/.wgetrc`

```
ca_certificate={file.pem}
```

(mind the _; it is not a [typo](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html#Wgetrc-Commands))

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I followed the steps. But I didn't have a key, so I used openssl to convert from .cer to .pem. 

openssl x509 -in certnew.cer -outform pem -out certnew.pem

I'm still facing the same issue as before.

Comment: any thoughts? Is the key required for the cert to work?